# Shell script stop running with background process

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'm trying to run the mysqld in bg to execute some command with the mysql client but my script stop running when I fg my process, here is the script I use

```sh
set -m
daemon="/usr/bin/mysqld --user=mysql --console --skip-name-resolve --skip-networking=0 $@"
$daemon &
exec echo "Test"
exec fg %1
```

I'm not an expert for shell scripting, I check in some website and I found this way to execute my command.

Answer (score 0):

No. The script stop after the `exec echo "Test"`. The `exec` replaces the current process (the shell script) with the command after it. You can verify this with:

```
daemon="/usr/bin/mysqld --user=mysql --console --skip-name-resolve --skip-networking=0 $@"
$daemon &
exec echo "Test"
echo "Second Test"
exec fg %1
```

The solution is simple: don't use `exec`.

BTW: it is unclear why you would want to do a `fg` in a shell script. `fg` has only a function in interactive shells, not in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thank you a lot, I found this command to do what i want, and it work

```sh
sh /scripts/run.sh & sleep 2 \
        && mysql -utest -ppass mydb < \
        /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mydb.sql
```

For the foreground process I didn't know that fg only work in interactive thank you for your precision.